# Unable to start program. [VALUE].dll is not a valid Win32 application error in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, visual-studio-2017

I have developed an C#, ASP.NET web application in a Windows 7 machine using Visual Studio 2012. Now i had imported the entire project into VS 2017 running on windows 10 machine, and when i try to enter the debugging mode to analyze my code it shows the following error:

[image]

I guess the project configurations are conflicting hence it throws this error. 
Any suggestions??

Comment: Try setting up your web project as the start-up project and then retry.

Comment: @CodingYoshi sorry but i am new to VS could you please elaborate? How can i do that?

Comment: Right click the web project and on of the options should be *set as startup* or something similar.

Comment: I experienced this issue once, randomly. I fixed it by restarting Visual Studio and installing the available package updates. (There will be a highlighted flag in the upper right if you have updates available.) [This user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36879401/8116884) also has a solution to a similar or the same problem, but I can't personally vouch for it.

Answer (score 27):

The same error happens when Visual Studio solution has selected the wrong Startup Project. The bold project is the designated startup project.

Go to the Solution Explorer > Right click on the correct project and select "Set as StartUp Project" in the context menu.

Answer (score 14):

I also got this error. I ultimately got to know that I was not selecting .sln file.

In VS, you should select .sln file and it automatically loads the complete project structrue is what I learnt.

Selecting .sln file worked for me

Comment: also try to double-clicking the .sln file.  If the .sln not visible, click the "show all Files" icon in solution explorer

Answer (score 7):

These errors are ***mostly*** because you are not selecting the .sln or solution file. In your solution explorer tree, double click the solution file and then build and run.

This runs contrary to a users intuition that simply opening a file and running it would work. Consider it a poor user interface. Jet Brains Rider, for instance, does not have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Change [Targeting Platforms with the Configuration Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185328.aspx) and Build the project then try to debug it.I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't export the project folder. upload the .sln file.
It will work.

[image]

Comment: Try to provide a short hint about your answer. so that it will reach very soon. link never help

Answer (score 0):

DLLs cannot be ran/debugged directly. You have to specify host application in the
***Configuration Properties>Debugging>Command*** and then let it load the DLL by itself.

You will most likely need to copy the DLL to the directory searchable by the host application e.g. its root or ./plugins folder.
In the ***Configuration Properties>Build Events>Post-Build Event>Command Line*** simply enter something like:

```
copy "$(TargetPath)" "$(HOST_APP)\plugins"
```

Answer (score 0):

The Startup Item needs to be a `.exe` file. It's looking at `BusinessLayer.dll` because BusinessLayer is currently the Startup Project.

First, build the solution. Then, set the Solution Explorer to folder view and find the `.exe` in one of you project's `/bin` folders. Right click on it and set it to the Startup Item.

Finally, click the play button in Visual Studio top bar.

**EDIT:** Basically the same as Thomas' answer, but I'm pointing out that the "correct project" is the one with the `.exe` file. I would have commented on his answer, but I have less than 50 rep right now.