# Unable to start .NET MVC application in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to run .NET MVC 4.6.1 app in a visual studio 2022.
I am able to build it successfully but unable to start.

Solution tried :

- Restarted VS
- Deleted bin folder
- Deleted .vs and suo

Nothing worked.

[image: DLL Error]

[image: Web Section]

Comment: _" .NET MVC 4.6.1"_ Do you mean an ASP.NET MVC application on .NET Framework 4.6.1? If so, what version of ASP.NET are you using?

Comment: My bad. ASP.NET MVC version is 5.2.7.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to start program. \[VALUE\].dll is not a valid Win32 application error in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48602869/unable-to-start-program-value-dll-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-error-in-v)

Comment: No, I have correct project setup as "Set up as Startup project"

Comment: For now I have deleted Repo and cloned it again. It is now working fine now.